# Add object's values as TreeMap values

Tags: object, treemap

I will try to clarify my problem description from a previous question.
I have a class like that:

```
class Edge{

       Integer from;
       Integer to;
       Integer sign;
       Long time;
    }
```

And a TreeMap of this type:

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Edge>> edgesByCluster = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Edge>>();
```

So my question is: Let's say that I have created an object edge like that:

```
Edge edge = new Edge();
edge.from = from[edgeCounter-1];
edge.to = to[edgeCounter-1];
edge.sign = sign[edgeCounter-1];
edge.time = time[edgeCounter-1];
```

Where the values for edge.from, edge.to, edge.sign and edge.time are read from a file. How can I add the object values as values of the edgesByCluster TreeMap? Meaning, what is the correct syntax to do so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.  You have a list of Edge objects.  This list is identified by an integer.  This list is placed in a map of such lists, where each list is identified by its integer.

You create an Edge object.  You want to put this in the TreeMap.  I'm going to assume that you want to add the Edge to an existing list; if you want to add a completely new list the process won't be that different.

First, you need the integer that identifies the target list.  I'll assume you have one (`id` below); you'd probably get it from the same place you got all the other Edge data.

```
ArrayList<Edge>  list = edgesByCluster.get( new Integer( id ) );
```

This finds the list in the TreeMap.  `get` wants an object, so I turn the `int` into an Integer.  (Personal preference:  I avoid autoboxing in Java.)  Note that `list` is still in the TreeMap; we didn't remove it.

Alternatively, you could add a new list to edgesByCluster:

```
ArrayList<Edge>  list = new ArrayList<Edge>();
edgesByCluster.put( new Integer( id ), list );
```

Now you have the list you want, just add the Edge object to it:

```
list.add( edge );
```

And you're done.  Your Edge instance is in EdgesByCluster.

This is probably not going to solve all your problems, but it should give you a start.

Comment: Hello RalphChapin, yes this is actually a start to get this going! Seems clear enough! Thank you for answering.